# How to sum the total of all categorical variables across several columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that looks something like this:

```
id AttA AttB AttC
1   Y         Y
2        Y
```

I would like to create another column which has the total number of attributes for each case, as follows:

```
id AttA AttB AttC TotalAtts
1   Y         Y     2
2        Y          1
```

It's not obvious to me how I should approach this problem, since I'm fairly new to Pandas.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is `'Y'` the only attribute value? What are those blanks, `NaN` or `''`?. Probably just `df.eq('Y').sum(1)`

Comment: If those are NaN or None then you could do a `count` like this: df['TotalAtts'] = df.count(axis=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check which cells in the dataframe are not empty with `ne('')`, and take the `sum` setting `axis` to `1`:

```
df['TotalAtts'] = df.ne('').sum(1)

   AttA AttB AttC  TotalAtts
0    Y         Y          2
1         Y               1
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to use `notnull()` to do the count, but I got there eventually.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the count of `Y`, you can do `(df == 'Y').sum(1)`. If you want to count non-null values, then you can do `df.count(1)`, but empty strings will be counted by this.